# Kivy Async Image - Static Google API doesn't load

Tags: asynchronous, google-api, kivy, google-maps-static-api

i try to asyncronously load a static google maps image via the google api.
The code below is taken from the kivy reference base, it works with other images, but not if i use the google link. The link works fine in the web browser. (Also note that the source string is in one line in my original py file, that just doesn't display right here)

**my kv**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.lang import Builder


class TestAsyncApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AsyncImage(
                source='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/'+\
                    'staticmap?center=47.909,7.85&zoom=13&size=600x300')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestAsyncApp().run()
```

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Kivy 1.8.0, URLs like the one above don't work as expected. Kivy tries to parse the URL and find the file extension, which fails of course. In the development version, we now check the MIME type reported by the server, but you can work around this in 1.8.0 by using a fake query parameter:

```
return AsyncImage(
        source='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/'+\
            'staticmap?center=47.909,7.85&zoom=13&size=600x300&ext=.png')
```